# popup window with combobox in wince

Tags: c, visual-c++, windows-ce, win32gui

I am fairly new to wince interface design.  I would like lunch a popup screen with couple of comboboxes. I would like know the best for doing that,  I have tried to do that with a dialog and createwindowex,  but I could not get to work.  Is there any simple application on this?

Thank you,
Liang

Comment: Side note: Can't you use the .NET Compact Framework? It would safe you a lot of trouble.

Comment: I really can not go that way!

Comment: I resolved my problem with the example form the following link http://www.functionx.com/win32/controls/combobox.htm